# Numeric value of char in Java

Tags: java, char, numeric

I am working with chars in java. I was expecting same result from the two print statements in the code:

```
char x = 'A';
System.out.println(Character.getNumericValue(x));
System.out.println(0 + x);
```

What am I missing here? Why does the first line give 10 and the second one 65?

Comment: Did you read JavaDock for `getNumericValue`. If so what exactly you have problem to understand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting chars (Casting vs. .getNumericValue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26185452/converting-chars-casting-vs-getnumericvalue)

Answer (score 0):

The [javadoc for `Character.getNumericValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html#getNumericValue(char)) states:

> Returns the int value that the specified Unicode character represents.

0' to '9' return 0 to 9 because these are the values that they represent. The Javadoc explains explicitly that

> The letters A-Z in their uppercase ('\u0041' through '\u005A'), lowercase ('\u0061' through '\u007A'), and full width variant ('\uFF21' through '\uFF3A' and '\uFF41' through '\uFF5A') forms have numeric values from 10 through 35.

This is nice because that's how different base-numbers, like base-16 (hexadecimal), are usually represented.

`System.out.println(0 + x);` will just give you the numeric value of the character, which is the follows the Unicode UTF-16 encoding, as that is what a Java `char` value represents.

Answer (score -1):

Character.getNumericValue(x)  ：Returns an int value for the specified Unicode character.
System.out.println(0 + x);   ：Returns the ASCII code of the specified character

Comment: `System.out.println(0 + x)` is a void function and doesn't return anything.

Comment: x is the character A,Try it for yourself, System.out.println(0 + x)== 0+65

Comment: @Hazel Printing is not the same as returning.